# Connecting to SQL Server from R which is Running on Remote UNIX Machine

Tags: sql-server, odbc, unix, unixodbc, r

We have a UNIX machine which includes R engine on it and installed SQL Server ODBC Driver 11.

We need to connect R to SQL Server. SQL Server currently works on another machine, so we tried to connect R to SQL Server with the code below.

```
library(RODBC)

dbhandle <- odbcDriverConnect('driver=ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server;server=10.XXX.XX.XX:1663;')
```

But getting that error:

> Warning messages: 1: In odbcDriverConnect("driver=ODBC Driver 11 for
>   SQL Server;server=10.XXX.XX.XX:1663;") :
>
> [RODBC] ERROR: state HYT00, code 0, message [unixODBC][Microsoft][ODBC
>   Driver 11 for SQL Server]**Login timeout expired** 2: In
>   odbcDriverConnect("driver=ODBC Driver 11 for SQL
>   Server;server=10.XXX.XX.XX:1663;") :
>
> [RODBC] ERROR: state 08001, code 87, message
>   [unixODBC][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]**A network-related
>   or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a
>   connection to SQL Server.** Server is not found or not accessible. Check
>   if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow
>   remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.
>   3: In odbcDriverConnect("driver=ODBC Driver 11 for SQL
>   Server;server=10.XXX.XX.XX:1663;") :
>
> [RODBC] ERROR: state 08001, code 87, message
>   [unixODBC][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]SQL Server Network
>   Interfaces: Connection string is not valid [87]. 4: In
>   odbcDriverConnect("driver=ODBC Driver 11 for SQL
>   Server;server=10.XXX.XX.XX:1663;") : ODBC connection failed

If I run telnet to SQL Server from UNIX machine, it works perfectly. I mean there is a healthy connection between these two machine.

How can we connect R to SQL Server without using DSN?

Comment: Please don't cross-post between SE sites http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35868420/connecting-to-sql-server-from-r-which-is-running-on-remote-unix-machine

Comment: Why? @MarkSinkinson

Comment: Because that's the general rule of Stack Exchange http://DBA.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: OK thanks for information. @MarkSinkinson I will obey this rule next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed delimiter which between server and port from `:` to `,` . It fixed my problem.

```
dbhandle <- odbcDriverConnect('driver=ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server;server=10.XXX.XX.XX,1663;')
```

Answer (score 0):

`Connection string is not valid` is the key error message there, I think.

Try:

```
dbconnection <- odbcDriverConnect("Driver=ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server;
                Server=10.XXX.XX.XX:1663; Database=YOURDBNAME; 
                Uid=USERID; Pwd=PASSWORD")
```

Comment: Nothing changed @Phil